# Received stripe error: Customer cus_*** already has the maximum 3 current and scheduled subscriptions

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

After creating more than **3 subscriptions** for a customer, I get the following error: *Customer cus_*** already has the maximum 3 current and scheduled subscriptions.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved after contacting stripe customer support:
[customer support response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAloN.png)

Only customers with **Test Clock** have a limit of **3 subscriptions per customer**

In other customers, this figure reaches **500 per customer**